# ACTION_CALL is not working in Samsung Galaxy S5(Lollipop 5.0) in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I have calling feature in my app. after clicking call button a call is directly made to the selected number. Its working in each and every device except Samsung galaxy S5. In Samsung galaxy S5 call is being disconnected instantly by just showing calling screen for microseconds. Below is the code I am using.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"
                            + Common.getPreferences(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "CONTACTNUMBER")));
                    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);

                    startActivity(callIntent);
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Why do you use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION flags? All examples I can find use no flags...I am not sure if it is the problem, but did you try it without the flags?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way given code also work on kitkat :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123456"));           
startActivity(intent);
```

Note : add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission andrenter code hereoid:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: still i am facing that props,:(